# C++ code and objects from C?

Tags: c++, c, lisp

Is there a simple way to work with C++ objects directly from C?
I want to expose some classes from C++ to C or to FFI(foreign function interface).
Sure, I can write a stuff like that:

```
class Foo{
....
};

void *make_foo(...){
Foo *ptr = new Foo(..)

return static_cast<void *>(ptr);
}

..

int *foo_method1(void *fooptr, ...){
Foo *ptr = static_cast<Foo*>(fooptr);
}
```

But there is a simpler method?

Comment: May I ask what this has to do with Lisp?

Comment: It is a part of a more general question of exposing C++ classes to Common Lisp though CFFI(or lisp implementation dependant FFI).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That, in general, is the simplest method.

Remember, too, that you'll need to use `extern "C"` on all of your C "wrapper" methods, as well.

Answer (score 7):

You almost there.  Prefix your standalone functions with `extern "C"` to turn off the C++ compiler's [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

For example:

```
extern "C" void *make_foo(...){
  Foo *ptr = new Foo(..)

  return static_cast<void *>(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a simpler way to do it. You could use  [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to go to another language with user defined types that are more than aggregates of data, but converting to C you'll have to use C's idea of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Verrazano/Fetter](http://common-lisp.net/project/fetter/) to generate [CFFI](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/) bindings for C++ code.
But it requires GCC-XML and I'm not sure about its portability.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible, then have your classes derive from a struct. You can then use  pointers to this struct in the C code:

```
// C++ code
extern "C" struct Cfoo {};
extern "C" struct Cbar {};

class foo : public Cfoo {};
class bar : public Cbar {};

// C API
extern "C" {
    struct Cfoo;
    struct Cbar;
}
```

It's not strictly an error, however gcc at least warns about converting between pointers with different types.

```
void foo (void) {
    struct Cfoo * pf;
    struct Cbar * pb;
    pf = pb;        // gcc warns
}
```

If you cannot inherit, then use a similar idea but have the C structure store a pointer to the C++ object, and again just forward declare the structures in the C API:

```
// C++ code
class foo {};
class bar {};

extern "C" struct Cfoo { foo * pFoo; };
extern "C" struct Cbar { bar * pBar; };

// C API
extern "C" {
    struct Cfoo;
    struct Cbar;
}
```

The disadvantage here is that the lifetime of the Cfoo and Cbar object needs to be taken care of.